Auth0: How to export/download/save users search results into csv or other file?
Found list of users i need in Auth0->dashboard->Users using "Lucene Syntax (Advanced)".
30 pages = 300 users.
But How to export/download/save info about these users into csv or other file ?
Like emails for example . . .
Thank you
